# big query function failed

Tags: python, mysql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

UPTAED:
i tested this function on cloud functions getting this error `Error: function terminated` . When I look at the logs: `in open_connection raise errors.InterfaceError( mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '111.111.111:3306' (110 Connection timed out)`

I'm trying to create a function that pulls data from mysql and loads it into big query but the function doesn't work on big query. Here is my code.

```
import mysql.connector
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd
def test(request):

    client = bigquery.Client()
        
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                host='host',
              user='user',
              password='password',
              database="db")
              
            
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("my_query")
            
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall() 
        
            
            
    df=pd.DataFrame(myresult,columns=mycursor.column_names)
        
    dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset_name')    
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.autodetect = True
    job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
    load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
                df, 'datasetname.tablename', job_config=job_config
    )
    print("Starting job {}".format(load_job))
    return ("Done!", 200)
```

Here is the requirements.txt:

```
mysql-connector==2.2.9
google-cloud-bigquery==2.3.1
google-cloud-storage==1.32.0
pandas==1.3.1
```

When I run the function with spyder without the request parameter, it works fine.

Comment: what does "not work" mean?

Comment: updated question. i solved the problem i mentioned but when i tested this function on cloud functions getting this error Error: `function terminated` . When I look at the logs: `in open_connection raise errors.InterfaceError( mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '111.111.111:3306' (110 Connection timed out)`

Comment: What the authorised network on your Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have permission to access this page. What do you say to the answer below? Thanks for your feedbacks by the way.

Comment: You need to provide more information on your cloud functions and cloud sql instance. Do you use the public or the private IP of your Cloud SQL? If private, do you use a serverless VPC connector? Is the cloud SQL instance in the same project or in another one?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud functions run in a different environment from the rest of your project.

They can connect to the internet; but not to your project resources unless you explicitly configure that access.

What you need to do is configure a [VPC Serverless Access connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#create-connector).

When you assign this connector to a cloud function, it will allow you to connect to resources in that VPC (cloud sql, compute instances, etc.).